# Mips assembly save return value into specific adress

Tags: assembly, architecture, mips, computer-science, mips32

So I have a procedure (function) that returns a value in $v0, in the main I move it into $s0 to save it for later.

Now from $s0 if I want to save the value at adress 0xFFFF0010 how would I write that ?
I seen that lui and ori can be used but i'm not sure how to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can use `lui`/`ori`, or simply the pseudo `la` if you are allowed to. Hell, some assemblers even support stuff like `sw $s0, foo`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out right after posting the question:

so lets say I have

```
li $s0, 4             # Value 4 saved in register $s0
lui $s1, 0xFFFF       # FFFF as first 16 bits
ori $s1, 0x0010       # 0010 as last 16 bits
sw $s0, ($s1)         # Saves the value 4 at address 0xFFFF0010
```